# Radiogroups not behaving properly in emulators

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have dynamically created `RadioButtons` and added them to a `Radiogroup`. Later `Radiogroup` is added to a `LinearLayout`.
My problem is, everything works fine in a device, but emulators.
In emulators I can select all the radio buttons, contrary to its behaviour.

Any clue?

Sample xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/sam_bg"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReportTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/mediumblue"
        android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/llGtResponseContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sample code to create `Radiobuttons` and `Radiogroup`

```
public LinearLayout getLayout(ViewGroup vg) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_type, vg, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_single);
    if(isCompulsory) {
        question = "• " + question;
    }
    tv.setText(question);
    radioView = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.single_rg);
    for(String i : responseArray) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
        // rb.setText(i);
        String str = i;
        if(str.trim().split("\\|").length > 1) {
            rb.setText((str.trim().split("\\|"))[0]);
            rb.setTag((str.trim().split("\\|"))[1]);
        }
        else {
            rb.setText(str);
            rb.setTag(str);
        }
        radioView.addView(rb);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Later the returned `View` returned from above method is then added to a `LinearLayout` which is again contained within a `ScrollView`.

Comment: It is always advised to post your XML code for a better understandings

Comment: Edited my questions with some sample code. A class has the method named getlayout(), which is called for array of instances.

Comment: Any hint is highly appreciated. Although I am also curious if Emulators can really behave this strange.

Comment: Resolved. Supply RadioButtons with "id". Refer [Posted solution by Janmejoy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436513/android-radiobuttons-misbehaving-on-emulator-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply "id" to RadioButtons by setId() method.
Below is sample code:

```
rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            rb[i]=new RadioButton(this);
            rb[i].setText("rdo"+i);
            rb[i].setId(i);
            rgroup.addView(rb[i]);


        }
```

Refered from [Android RadioButtons misbehaving on Emulator only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436513/android-radiobuttons-misbehaving-on-emulator-only)

Still the reason is unknown for different behavior on Emulator and real devices.