# Android RadioButtons misbehaving on Emulator only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have RadioGroup in xml. And I am filling it with RadioButton from code.
Problem is, in Emulators RadioButtons do not behave w.r.t RadioGroup. I can select all radiobuttons at once. But everything seems to work fine on real device.

**Below are screenshots and code for all files:**

**Screenshot from emulator**

[image: Screenshot from emulator]

**Screenshot from device Samsung Galaxy**

[image: Screenshot from device Samsung galaxy]

**Source for MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private RadioGroup rg;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.myradio, rg,true);
    }

}
```

}

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</RadioGroup>
```

**myradio.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
```

Comment: @Avadhani Btw, layout is not my concern but behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be like this

```
public class example extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private RadioGroup rgroup;
     RadioButton rb;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);


        rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            rb[i]=new RadioButton(this);
            rb[i].setText("rdo"+i);
            rb[i].setId(i);
            rgroup.addView(rb[i]);


        }

    }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: I dont want to change the approach creating layout. Because my need is dynamic. Plus, you might have noticed that this code works fine on devices.

Comment: @Avinazz .k...i will try differently

Comment: I have no issues with generating this layout with any approach, but it has to be dynamic. I can do the same thing in several different ways, but emulators still ditch me. BTW, m working on Android since 2 yrs, and i still make silly mistakes, which I dont think is the case here.

Comment: Sure and let me know if you end up with this same behavior.

Comment: Wow, working. Accepted. All I have to do was assign some id to it. But I am still wondering why it behaves differently on Emulator as compared to real Devices.